# how to read a set of lines with each line having CRLF(\r\n) as delimiter using java

Tags: java, delimiter

Using java how can i read a paragraph with each line having a delimiter CRLF(\r\n).
For example

4\r\n
This\r\n
8\r\n
response\r\n

I want to extract 4 and store it into buffer and then read 8 and store for this paragraph.
Please help me.

Comment: Where does the file come from? Why is each word preceded by its length?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question, do you want to read '4','This','8', 'response', or as jlordo says the numbers are the length of the words that follow? I can't see any use case where this is required as long as you stick to a specific delimiter.

Comment: I want to read http response in the case of chunked transfer encoding.Each chunk comes with size and chunk data.So I need only size and each chunk has delimiter \r\n.In such case I need it.

Comment: Using BufferedReader how can I get the 4 and 8 as I needed those integers.How can I split them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you have to do but if you have to get the strings from your text you can do it by following my solution.

It may be not the best way but it works using `StringTokenizer` and by giving `\r\n` as delimiter.

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer("4\r\n This\r\n 8\r\n response\r\n", "\r\n");

//iterate through tokens
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String str = st1.nextToken();
    System.out.println(str);          
}
```

This will print

> 4
>
> This
>
> 8
>
> response

This, of course, is useful if you're not reading from a file but you've just got the full string and you need to extract data from it.

If you're reading from a file you should check the other answers as `BufferedReader.readLine` is the right way.

EDIT:

Here's the new code:

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer("4\r\n This\r\n 8\r\n response\r\n", "\r\n");

//iterate through tokens
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String str = st1.nextToken();
    try{
        //Integer.parseInt throws an exception in the input String doesn't represent a number so we catch the exception and we simply skip it. This will just output each number in your string.
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
        System.out.println(i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){}            
}
```

Now it just ouputs:

> 4
>
> 8

Comment: thank you.But I want to have in my output 4 and skip \r\n and skip "this" and again I want 8.How can I do this one?

Comment: Thank you..I tried and I am getting.But I want to achieve this with BufferedReader.I want to read until \r\n and store only digit 4 into ByteArrayOutputBuffer.Can u help me?

Comment: I mean I want to read the digits from the above example.4 and 8 using while loop as while(line!=null) I want to read until \r\n so for the first time I get "4\r\n" and then I want to store only 4 into ByteArrayOutPutBuffer.And later I want get 5 as above.How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BufferedReader.readLine()` to just read the lines, or `Scanner` if you want to automically parse the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what *output* you require, but the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) class will allow you to read a text file line by line. There are several examples available [on the internet](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/).

The `readLine` method will do the following:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Comment: I want to read the digits from the above example.4 and 8 using while loop as while(line!=null) I want to read until \r\n so for the first time I get "4\r\n" and then I want to store only 4 into ByteArrayOutPutBuffer.And later I want get 5 as above.How can I achieve this

Comment: In the while loop check to see if the line that was read (which won't include \r\n) is a digit. StepTNT's answer above gives one way of doing that.